# 'Travelling Salesman Problem' solver app for iPhone

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, google-maps

Is there iPhone App to solve the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP) for real world addresses?

I found solver for [OSM data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman)?

But I can not find in [repo](http://travelingsales.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/travelingsales/trunk/) sources for iPhone.

Comment: [TSP Solver for OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman) says that IPhone is supported platform. There is [online solver using Google Maps](http://www.josef-graef.de/karten/tsp/index.html)

Comment: You might get a response to this if you post to cs-theory on stack exchange.
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How would this work in practice as opposed to a theoretical exercise? Real world addresses means tight integration to an up-to date road map database which means that you will need to restrict your area from the globe to an area where this data is available. I see this as a nice armchair exercise, but fail to see what problem you are facing today and how this can be answered in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is remotely close. I'd watch the [Wolfram Alpha](http://itunes.apple.com/app/wolframalpha/id334989259?mt=8) app as they'd be my obvious choice for someone that would enable a "mail the data" to their servers for a solution.

iOS is certainly powerful enough to solve this class of problems, but we're still waiting for someone to invest the time in releasing an "app for that".